# Page with multiple dropdown filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page which uses dropdowns to filter a listing. I have over 10 filters now and each of the change function, I am calling an AJAX request and passing corresponding variables to the PHP function. Like this :

```
$("#categories").change(function() {
  uri = "myurl" ;
  var status=$("#statusfilter").val();
  var category=$("#categories").val();
  var network=$("#networksfilter").val();
  var prod_type = $("#prodtypefilter").val();
  loadData(uri,category,status,network,prod_type);
});
```

and in loadData() I have the following code :

```
function loadData(uri,category,status,network,prod_type){
  url + = category+"/"+status+"/"+network+"/"+prod_type;
  $('#userdata').load(url); 
}
```

Here I have given only 4 filters only, but it is actually 10 and may increase.Anyway this is working fine. But the problem is that as I increase the filters, I need to write this same for every dropdown change function. Is there any better approach to optimze the code and so  I don't need to load a bunch of JS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your filter elements' IDs to start with same word, for example "filter_". Then get all of them at once:

```
$('select[id^="filter_"]').change(function() {
    var uri = "myurl";
    var filters = new Array();

    $('select[id^="filter_"]').map(function () { 
        filters[$(this).name()] = $(this).val(); // not tested, just an idea
    });

    loadData(uri,filters);
});
```

`.map()` iterates over its elements, invoking a function on each of them and recording the selected option value in the array.

You can use `.each()` if it's more intuitive from `.map()` for you:

```
$.each('select[id^="filter_"]', function() {
   filters[$(this).name()] = $(this).val(); // not tested, just an idea
});
```

**Note:** It's a good idea to use associative array as @Tony noticed below to be sure which filter is for which database table attribute in your server side script.

Comment: Great, but I guess order of filters can be important.

Comment: This is something great. But I am getting no value in filters when I alert it. I am getting all the dropdwon values if I alert inside the map function and I am getting corresponding names.

Comment: ha it some issue with toString(). Working fine now :) Thanks enenen :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write some code in any cases, but you can reduce it, for example like this:

```
$("#categories").change(function() {
   uri = "myurl";

   var filters = {
     status: $("#statusfilter").val(),
     category: $("#categories").val(),
     network: $("#networksfilter").val(),
     prod_type: $("#prodtypefilter").val()
   }; // order is important

   loadData(filters );
});

loadData(filters) {
  var url = '';
  for (var filterName in filters)
     url += '/' + (filters[filterName] || 'any'); // here some def value needed

  url = url.substring(1); // cut first slash
  $('#userdata').load(url);
}
```

**EDIT**

Or even like this:

```
loadData(filters) {
  var url = Object.keys(filters).map(function(el) {
      return filters[el] || 'any';
  }).join('/');

  $('#userdata').load(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tony for the answer. using enenen solutions as it reduces the JS significantly.